# Cannot connect to Jackal clear path from my laptop

Tags: ros, jackal, ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully connected the jackal robot to a wifi network by ssh ing to the jackal through an ethernet cable, so my robot has a working internet connection. When I follow the steps outlined in the clear path tutorial at this link https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/jackal/network.html and then do rostopic list, I get the error message: "ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297000/cannot-connect-to-jackal-clear-path-from-my-laptop/) by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2018-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need your computer to be able to connect to Jackal’s ROS master. This means you need to set the jackal as ROS master. In order to do this you need to do the following:

Open a new terminal on your machine and enter:

```
ifconfig
```

Here you need to find your Ethernet IP. It will be something like 192.168.x.x

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 09:00:12:90:e3:e5  
      inet addr:192.168.1.29 Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe70:e3f5/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:54071 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:48515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:22009423 (20.9 MiB)  TX bytes:25690847 (24.5 MiB)
      Interrupt:10 Base address:0xd020
```

Then in an ssh-ed window type ifconfig again and find the Ethernet IP which is also 192.168.y.y
Then open a new terminal on your machine and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Here you need add the jackal IP and the host name for the jackal. For example like :

```
192.168.y.y cpr-jackal-0001
```

where you replace .y.y with what you got with ifconfig in the ssh-ed window. After this you can create a simple bash script called **remote-jackal.sh** with only the following lines inside:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://cpr-jackal-0001:11311  # Jackal's hostname
export ROS_IP=192.168.x.x                           # Your laptop's ethernet IP address
```

where you replace .x.x with what you got with ifconfig in the first step.
Now for every terminal that you want to use/connect with the jackal's ROS master you just need to source the remote-jackal.sh file you created like:

```
source remote-jackal.sh
```

After this when you type **rostopic list** your should get the published topics.

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dkrivet](https://answers.ros.org/users/36368/dkrivet/) on 2018-07-11**:
This has worked. Thank you very much!